# Python Printing on the same Line

Tags: python, printing, formatting

The problem that I have is printing phone_sorter() and number_calls() all on the same lines. For instance it will print the two lines of phone_sorter but the number_calls will be printed right below it. I have tried the end='' method but it does not seem to work.

```
customers=open('customers.txt','r')
calls=open('calls.txt.','r')

def main():
    print("+--------------+------------------------------+---+---------+--------+")
    print("| Phone number | Name                         | # |Duration | Due    |")
    print("+--------------+------------------------------+---+---------+--------+")
    print(phone_sorter(), number_calls())

def time(x):
    m, s = divmod(seconds, x)
    h, m = divmod(m, x)
    return "%d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s)

def phone_sorter():
    sorted_no={}
    for line in customers:
        rows=line.split(";")
        sorted_no[rows[1]]=rows[0]
    for value in sorted(sorted_no.values()):
            for key in sorted_no.keys():
                if sorted_no[key] == value:
                    print(sorted_no[key],key)                            
def number_calls():
    no_calls={}
    for line in calls:
        rows=line.split(";")
        if rows[1] not in no_calls:
            no_calls[rows[1]]=1
        else:
            no_calls[rows[1]]+=1
    s={}
    s=sorted(no_calls.keys())
    for key in s:
        print(no_calls[key]) 
main()
```

Comment: In Python2.7, you only need to end with a comma. `print 'output',`

Comment: This is python3 and I already tried the comma method.

Comment: @Kirill where are you even using `end=''` ?

Comment: If `print('output', end="")` didn't do it, I'm not sure what to tell you.

Comment: in the last print of phone_sorter and number_calls, it wasn't working it so I just removed it.

Comment: And how wasn't it working - please provide more information rather than code that doesn't use what you tried, and with no information about why it's not perceived to work

Comment: I've not thought through this too much, but isn't there a line break character in the original string?  so perhaps you need to do `line.strip().split(';')`?  This is in addition to the point raised by AlexMartelli of course, since `print(None, None)` certainly makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Your key problem is that both `phone_sorter` and `number_calls` do their own printing, and return `None`.  So, printing their return values is absurd and should just end with a `None None` line that makes no sense, after they've done all their own separate-line printing.

A better approach is to restructure them to **return**, not **print**, the strings they determine, and only then arrange to `print` those strings with proper formatting in the "orchestrating" `main` function.

It looks like they'll each return a `list` of strings (which they are now printing on separate lines) and you'll likely want to `zip` those lists if they are in corresponding order, to prepare the printing.

But your code is somewhat opaque, so it's hard to tell if the orders of the two are indeed corresponding.  They'd better be, if the final printing is to make sense...

Added: let me exemplify with some slight improvement and one big change in `phone_sorter`...:

```
def phone_sorter():
    sorted_no={}
    for line in customers:
        rows=line.split(";")
        sorted_no[rows[1]]=rows[0]
    sorted_keys = sorted(sorted_no, key=sorted_no.get)
    results = [(sorted_no[k], k) for k in sorted_keys]
    return results
```

Got it?  Apart from doing the computations better, the core idea is to put together a **list** and return it -- it's `main`'s job to format and print it appropriately, in concert with a similar list returned by `number_calls` (which appears to be parallel).

```
def number_calls():
    no_calls=collections.Counter(
        line.split(';')[1] for line in calls)
    return [no_calls(k) for k in sorted(no_calls)]
```

Now the relationship between the two lists is not obvious to me, but, assuming they're parallel, `main` can do e.g:

```
nc = no_calls()
ps = phone_sorter()
for (duration, name), numcalls in zip(ps, nc):
    print(...however you want to format the fields here...)
```

Those headers you printed in `main` don't tell me what data should be printed under each, and how the printing should be formatted (width of
each field, for example).  But, `main`, and only `main`, should be
intimately familiar with these presentation issues and control them, while the other functions deal with the "business logic" of extracting the data appropriately.  "Separation of concerns" -- a big issue in programming!

Comment: Yes, they are all supposed to be printed on the same line, one row of phone numbers, name, # and so on. I tried return but it just prints one instance of the function and not the full dictionaries.

Comment: @Kirill, return a **list**, as I mentioned; then loop over those lists (likely `zip`ped) in `main`, printing as you go (with `end=' '` most likely, if all needs to be on a single line).